# importing external sqlite database in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic-framework

Hello sorry i am new to this. i am making an application that is suppose to add information about a building into a database while offline and sync with a server when the phone comes online. I will like to use an external sqlite db with my ionic project. How do i go about connecting to the external database.

Answer (score 1):

Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins :

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage

$ npm install --save @ionic-native/sqlite
```

After installing a plugin’s package, add it to your app’s NgModule.

Below is the sample code on using sqlite in your app for saving data

```
saveData() {
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'myionicdb.db', // Name of the Database
      location: 'default'
    }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
      db.executeSql('INSERT INTO expense VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)',[this.data.date,this.data.type,this.data.description,this.data.amount])
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
          this.toast.show('Data saved', '5000', 'center').subscribe(
            toast => {
              this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
            }
          );
        })
}
```